# Python: Convention for date with no year

Tags: python, date

I have a script that looks at a list of birthdays and then calculates the age. Some birthdays have year, month, day and some only have month, day.

For the ones with years, I have `dob = date(year, month, day)`

But for the ones without years, what is the appropriate convention for storing the date, since `date()` requires a year argument?

Right now I'm saying that everyone without a birth year was born in the year 1500 (so I can at least identify them easily later on), but it's obviously a stupid solution.

Comment: Agreed that your solution is probably the best. No there is no convention, and setting it arbitrarily (but CONSISTENTLY) will make life easy for whoever comes next. Just document it so they don't wrack their brain trying to figure out why you did `date(1500, month, day)`. Instead do something like `DEFAULT_YEAR = 1500`, `date(year or DEFAULT_YEAR, month, day)`. Remember "KISS". "Keep it simple, stupid" or my personal favorite: "Keep it stupidly simple."

Comment: Just make sure that you are using a leap year - which 1500 is, so you are good

Comment: It would be stupid if you planned to have birthdates in 1500 ... but assuming we are talking recent history that should be just fine ...

Comment: @user2782067 Thanks for the leap year reminder, although it doesn't matter in this case. If someone is "born in the year 1500", I'm obviously not going to try and calculate his/her age.

Comment: @AutomaticStatic I think it's more for the reason that someone legitimately born on February 29th will throw an exception if you used `date(1501, 2, 29)`. Note however that in my version of Python3, `date(1500, 2, 29)` erroneously throws an error.

Comment: @AdamSmith True, although I have a conditional such that age is not calculated if `year == 1500`.

Comment: actually, while 1500 is a valid leap year(due to being before the adoption of the gregorian calendar), it isn't considered one in python's datetime module. So 1504 might be better. But if it works, it works.

Comment: @user2782067. The year 1500 is **not** a leap year. Years that are evenly divisible by 100 must also be evenly divisible by 400 in order to be leap years. So 1600 was a leap year, but not 1500 or 1700.

Comment: An alternative to 1500 may be 9999, or 9996 if you want a leap year, or some other date far in the future.  It serves the same purpose as 1500; it is clearly not an actual birth year but leaves you with a valid date that you can manipulate.  This sort of technique has been used for æons (of computer time, at any rate).

Comment: @ekhumero it is a leap year, as a different rules apply before 1582 due to Gregorian vs Julian calendar... But kind of off topic

Comment: @user2782067: 1500 is not a leap year in *proleptic* Gregorian calendar used by `datetime` module. Try: `from datetime import date; date(1500, 2, 29)` it should raise `ValueError`, while `date(1504, 2, 29)` doesn't.

Comment: @user2782067. We're not talking about historical leap years (which is off-topic), but leap years according to the python `datetime` module. In that context, the year 1500 is not a leap year, for the reasons I stated.

Answer (score 4):

If there is no `year`; don't use `datetime.date` class. `date` must have `year`. Either compute `date` field on the fly everytime you need it if `year` is present, and/or make `self.date` property on your custom object to raise an error if it is used for an object without a year.

Comment: This is a potentially good solution, but in my case I will eventually have to put all dates into a standardized format, and `datetime.date` is probably the best choice. My strategy here is to handle leap year exceptions inside my age calculator function, and only pass dates to it if they have a year.

Answer (score 2):

I think it pays off to go a small extra mile when defining data structures (not with other things!) and not use a convention like your year `1500`. Thus:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Birthday:
    day: int
    month: int
    year: Optional[int] = None

    def is_valid(self) -> bool:
        try:
            dt = date(self.year, self.month, self.day)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
```

The `dataclass` is for extra convenience only when creating or printing a birthday. Now you can:

```
birthday_without_year = Birthday(day=3, month=5)
birthday_with_year = Birthday(day=3, month=5, year=2000)
```

If you want, you can overwrite the default `__init__` and check if the birthday `is_valid` if someone passes a year.